# jsPDF Issue - HTML is not rendering into PDF using jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

I am just trying to use jsPDF library to generate PDF on client side. In this PDF, I am writing data as well as taking few sections of html page. On my page, I have few tables that I want to capture in my pdf. For this, I am just trying to use jsPDF's html functions but they are throwing errors and table is not writing in PDF.

Below is the code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function generatePDF(){  
      let doc = new jsPDF();  
      doc.html($('#reading_stats'), { //reading_stats is "ID" of html table
          x: 10,
          y: 10
      });

      doc.save('test.pdf');
   }
</script>
```

After running above code, browser is throwing below error and PDF is generating with nothing:

[image]

I have also tried with another way to pass table html as given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function generatePDF(){  
      let doc = new jsPDF();  
      doc.html($('#reading_stats_container').html(), { //reading_stats_container is "ID" of html table parent div
          x: 10,
          y: 10
      });

      doc.save('test.pdf');
   }
</script>
```

After running above code, I am getting below error and PDF is generating with nothing:
[image]

I have seen jsPDF documentation as well as many solutions on google. All are using these logic to insert html into PDF.

I have also tried solution shared on below URL:
[Export HTML table to PDF using jsPDF](https://jsfiddle.net/ugD5L/806/)

To implement above URL solution, I have downgraded my jsPDF version to 1.2.6 and used same logic(shared on above URL) but in this case PDF is rendering all cells of table in single vertical line.

Below is my html table that I am generating creating bootstrap css:

[image]

I am not able to understand why no solution is working for me. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var pdfdoc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdfdoc.fromHTML($('#reading_stats_container').html(), 10, 10, '',
function(callback){pdfdoc.save('First.pdf');});
});
```